# Handle Firebase Notification remote message when key is null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I receive the notification and get data why key is null my app crached

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        type = remoteMessage.getData().get("type");
        time = remoteMessage.getData().get("time");
        id = remoteMessage.getData().get("id");
    }
}
```

when `remoteMessage.getData().get("id")` is `null` my app crashes.

Comment: If `null` is indeed a valid value for `...get("id")`, then I'd guess you've declared your variable as `int id` whereas you probably want `Integer id`. `int` is a primitive type which can only represent integers while `Integer` is a reference type which can represent an integer reference or `null`.

Comment: when "id" not exist my app crache

Comment: Ok. _Should_ it always exist? If yes, then what you mean to ask is rather _why_ it is not set, in which case the code you posted is completely irrelevant. If no, then change `int id` to `Integer id`.

Comment: Thank you i change int to Integer

Comment: Did that solve your problem?

Comment: oh- no );   ,but when i send id=" " insted of id="" from server ,don't see crash

Comment: Can you post your crash report?

Comment: resolved it- i changed id from server - i sent id=" " insted of id=""